# iBeacon's customisable UUID conflicts

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

If my understanding is correct, there is a large range of UUIDs assigned in the [specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/service-discovery) - but then there's also [this](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx).

Since an iBeacon's UUID can be customised, wouldn't the UUID conflict with existing codes and create undesirable outcomes?

If my understanding is correct, the service UUIDs are at byte 30 and 31 of the BLE packet, which is overlapped by iBeacon's UUIDs. Service UUIDs are only 2 bytes so it can't be hard for collision to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand that there are two types of bluetooth advertisements:

- Service advertisements
- Manufacturer advertisements

Advertisements must be one type or the other, not both.

Only service advertisements use Service UUIDs (either 16 bit or 128 bit).  Manufacturer advertisements do not.  Manufacturer advertisements only have a two byte company code registered with Bluetooth SIG.  Everything else in the manufacturer advertisement is arbitrary data.

Beacon types like AltBeacon and iBeacon are manufacturer advertisements, so they do not contain Service UUIDs.  There is therefore no possible overlap between a ProximityUUID and a Service UUID, which are completely different things.

Other beacon types like Eddystone and Gimbal do use service advertisements which may be what is causing the confusion.

Comment: I see. Does the manufacturer code have to be registered with Bluetooth SIG? Also, is the position of the manufacturer ID arbitrary? I see that Altbeacon has it in Octets 2 and 3, whereas iBeacon seems to have it in Octets 5 and 6.

Comment: Yes, manufacturer ids are registered with Bluetooth SIG.  They are always in the same position (bytes 2-3 of the manufacturer adv PDU), so the reference you mention may show a proceeding flags PDU, which is sometimes present with advertisements.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting iBeacon UUIDs mixed up with 16-bit Service UUIDs.

iBeacon UUIDs are 16-bytes (byte, not bit) long, which means there are `2^(16 * 8)` possible combinations.

That's `3.4 * 10^38`, which is a lot. Bigger than Avogadro's constant, even. So there should never be a collision.

Service UUIDs, on the other hand, only have `2^16 = 65,536` combinations. But the Bluetooth SIG manages those to prevent collisions.

Comment: Yes, most assigned UUIDs are only 16-bites long. For instance, `0x180D` is assigned to heart rate monitors.

Comment: But if my understanding is correct, the service UUIDs are at byte 30 and 31 of the BLE packet, which is overlapped by iBeacon's UUIDs.

Comment: The typical iBeacon packet doesn't have service UUIDs. A service UUID usually indicates that the beacon has some function upon connecting to it. The main purpose of an iBeacon is to simply announce its presence to an application. If you do want to add a service UUID, say you have an iBeacon that offers heart rate information or configuration services, you should check the Bluetooth spec for how to put 16-bit service UUIDs into your packet. Google's Eddystone protocol uses service UUIDs to advertise UID, Telemtery, and URL data. Look into the Eddystone protocol on their GitHub for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they can, but hey 128-bit. It's gonna be hard that 2 people generate the same `UUID` by a random procedure.

If you wish to generate one randomly use the `uuidgen` command on your `OS X` terminal.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, the service UUIDs are at byte 30 and 31 of the BLE packet, which is overlapped by iBeacon's UUIDs. Service UUIDs are only 2 bytes so it can't be hard for collision to occur.

Answer (score 0):

The format and content of an iBeacon advertisement and a discoverable service advertisement are quite different.  So even though there may be some bytes at the end of the packet that have the same values the differences in the packet headers mean that there is no confusion as to the meaning of those bytes